# How to draw a vertical line between the columns of a multiple column list view in android?

Tags: android, android-listview

Right now i am working with multiple column list view in android.

My need is to draw a vertical line between the columns of a multiple column list view in android.Which means i am trying to show this multiple column list-view as like a Grid-View.
The below images will make you clear about my doubts,please find it

[image]

How to achieve this concept.Suggestions?

thanks in advance!..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dip"
    android:layout_below="@+id/te1"
    android:background="#F0FFFF" />
```

And check this links  http://thiranjith.com/2010/02/19/how-to-display-border-lines-with-tablelayouts/

http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-%E2%80%93-layouts-part-two-table-and-absolute-layouts/

Comment: in which xml this view should be placed?

Answer (score 0):

I think to show data in a row, you take a textview .

So put View between every textview.

```
<View
     android:layout_width="5dp"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:background="#ababab" />
```

So it display lie this.

```
Dev | 000000000000000000 | Chennai
PSl | 000000000000000000 | Mumbai
```

Comment: May i know reason fro DownVote ?