# Adding padding inside the listview with line

Tags: android, listview, padding

How can I add padding in each box inside my listview with 1dp line of divider I want each of my box to be bigger but

```
android:dividerHeight="10px"
android:divider="#FFCC00"
```

doesnt solve my problem as it give me thick line I just want each of the box inside the listview to be bigger with 1px of line. how can I do it?

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:background="#111"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:dividerHeight="1px"
    android:divider="#FFCC00"
     >
```

Comment: Give padding to the item layout

Comment: Are you inflating any row to the adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Use Padding in ListView

```
     android:paddingBottom="1dp"
```

Comment: do you know how to create line that is less than 1 dp?

Comment: Check this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12347003/how-to-draw-a-vertical-line-between-the-columns-of-a-multiple-column-list-view-i

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give padding to item in listview then use

```
android:padding="1dp"
```

I would suggest not to use px (read android docs)

Comment: do you know how to draw a line that is less than 1 dp?

Comment: If You want to have line between 2 items in list then                                      android:dividerHeight="5dp"
    android:divider="CCCC00" works fine..